# Receive manipulation events inside a SurfaceScrollViewer

Tags: c#, wpf, events, touch, pixelsense

I am currently developing a Surface 2.0 application. I am trying to develop a custom control that is able to be dragged and resized by touch. I figured the easiest way to do so would be manipulation events.

Problem: My custom controls reside inside a `SurfaceScrollViewer` and it seems that the ScrollViewer is stealing all manipulation events - they are never fired on my control. If I change the `SurfaceScrollViewer` to an ordinary `ScrollViewer` the manipulation events are fired fine. Example:

```
<s:SurfaceScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <local:CustomControl IsManipulationEnabled="True" ManipulationStarting="OnManipulationStarting" />
</s:SurfaceScrollViewer>
```

How can I receive manipulation events inside the `SurfaceScrollViewer`? I honestly have to say I don't even get why this is happening - isn't event bubbling supposed to prevent things like that? In my understanding, `CustomControl` should receive the event before the `SurfaceScrollViewer` and get a chance to handle it. Why is this not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The SurfaceScrollViewer needs to get all manipulation events to support panning, as explained in the *Remarks* section in [SurfaceScrollViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.surfacescrollviewer.aspx).

I guess if you want to disable this behaviour you could set the [PanningMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.panningmode.aspx) property to `None`, but then it might now longer feel like a SurfaceScrollViewer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was suspecting this, still I don't understand why I can't get manipulation events if a user control inside my `SurfaceScrollViewer` is touched (and let the user pan on the empty parts or let my children decide which manipulation events should bubble up). So are you saying there is no way to do this except for disabling panning (which makes the scroller much less useful)?

Comment: I'm not sure. Perhaps i'll give it a try when i find the time.